# Inline function call automatic element by id

Tags: javascript

I have a curiosity to ask, why by inserting the id directly in the onclick function, for example, the table is recalled?

```js
function See(table){
  console.log(table); // how system catch automatic the element?
}
```

```html
<table id='iamtable' border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td><button onclick='See(iamtable);'>press me</button>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd say you arer not passing the id, that would be See('iamtable'); your passing the object iamtable created the table-tag

Comment: But i didn't create var `lamtable` with for example `document.getElementById('lamtable')`

Comment: That part is explained by the answer of @eamanola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting an id to an element, creates a reference in window object. you can use

```
window.theid // or short theid
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('theid')
```

though this is not recommended

Comment: Yes but in my code i don't refer to window object

Comment: I tested the code without window and work, so what sense does it make to use `getElementById`?

Comment: everything is implicitly part of window object, eg document is window.document, console is window.console, etc...

Comment: Yes, but do you agree that it makes no sense to use the `getElementById` function if I implicitly already have an object?

Comment: makes sense. can't think of any situation where direct access would fail the app in a browser environment. maybe a legacy thing. ping me, if you ever run into a case against it.